# crontab doesnt work in linux but manually works

Tags: linux, shell, cron, sshpass

I made a shell script to connect using ssh with password to another linux server, get the details of a specific file and save it in a log file in the origin server. Manually works without problem but with the /etc/crontab doesnt update the file. (I think it may be the connection because if I try to write a test text in the file it works fine).

I tried with tee -a command and the >> command to update the file and both fails.

This is my code

```
#! /bin/bash

sshpass -p "password" ssh "username"@"ipserver" ls -l /filepath/file.txt | tee /home/user/test/details.log
```

I omitted the password, username and ip for discretion.

This is the /etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
 *  *  *  *  * user-name  command to be executed
*/1  *  *  *  * root    /home/test/script.sh
```

Hope you can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. My first question is, why do you run your script as `root`? This opens up security holes if the script itself or the directory `/home/test` is not owned by root.
2. If you are running the script as `root` from crontab, have you tested it as root from the command line?
3. I see directories `/home/test` and `/home/user/test` in your post. Do they really both exist and why?

Imho, what you should do:

1. Setup public key authentication between your user `test` and the remote user on the system. Use `ssh-keygen` to generate a public/private key pair, then copy the public key onto the target system and save it to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. This will eliminate you having to use sshpass and have the password in cleartext in your crontab file.
2. Test the script as user `test` and then install it in the user `test`'s crontab file. Simply type `crontab -e` as user test and you can add the same entry there.